# Why I can't use nullable type in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, nullable

I have a flutter project created in Jan 2019. I read an article in Dart and says that it support nullable type.

```
class c {
  int? id;
}
```

But I can't get the above to compile. It give some error message but has nothing to do with nullable type. Seems like it doesn't understand the '?' at all.

Error: [image]

May I know what might have missing in my code? Do I need to upgrade my Dart or Flutter? I looked at pubspec.yaml, but can't find any where that reference to dart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use null safety now, the official support for flutter should arrive at the beginning of next year, according to the flutter team, it is not yet ready for production. But if you just want to test it, update your sdk, sdk: "> = 2.7.0 <3.0.0"

You need to create an analysis_options.yaml file in the root of your flutter app and write something like

```
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

And also make sure you have a recent enough version of flutter

```
flutter upgrade
```

Michael Thomsen from Dart made this post today, where it explains more about null safety in Flutter. https://medium.com/flutter/null-safety-flutter-tech-preview-cb5c98aba187